# How to call class function from another file through url?

Tags: php, class, oop

**To do:** I want to call a function from **file-1.php** on another file which is **file-2.php** because I need to trigger the function through URL. For example, I access the url `http://localhost/sitename/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/file-2.php` it will trigger the `import()` function from **file-1.php** file.

Extra Info: I'm going to use cron job and point that url to trigger the function.

**file-1.php**

```
<?php
namespace Inc\Core;

class CronMethods
{
  public static function import() { 
    echo "Test";
  }
}
```

**file-2.php**

```
<?php

use Inc\Core\CronMethods;

CronMethods::import();
```

**Problem/Error**:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Inc\Core\CronMethods' not found in /var/www/html/padlab/wp-content/plugins/padlab/inc/cron.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/padlab/wp-content/plugins/padlab/inc/cron.php on line 5

Comment: first, include file1 to file2 then call your method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First include file1 to file2 then after call your method like.

**file-2.php**

```
<?php

 use Inc\Core\CronMethods;
 require_once(file1 path);

 CronMethods::import();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I like to organize classes.

All the class files will be in the `class` folder while all the namespaces have a separate folder for itself.

```
/class
    /Inc
        /Core
           CronMethods.php
autoload.php
file-2.php
```

Then use a [namespace friendly autoloader](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/autoload-classes-namespaces) to autoload classes.

**autoload.php**

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($className) {

    $className = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/class/' . $className . '.php';

});
```

**file-2.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'autoload.php';

use Inc\Core\CronMethods;
CronMethods::import();
```

In this way, you don't need to include all the class files, just the `autoload.php` file.